# Array in Java which has Javascript array-like nature

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

I have some reference code which is written in Javascript and I am trying to port it to Java.

The problem I have with the porting is that I don't have anything in Java which can be used as stack and normal array at the same time. The reference code uses an array object which can act as a normal array and also like a stack.

Is there anything which I can use to resolve my problem?

Reference Code:

```js
var ascii85 = function (input) {
    // input: Array: an array of numbers (0-255) to encode
    var result = [],
        reminder = input.length % 4,
        length = input.length - reminder;
    c(input, length, result);
    if (reminder) {
        var t = input.slice(length);
        while (t.length < 4) {
            t.push(0);
        }
        c(t, 4, result);
        var x = result.pop();
        if (x == "z") {
            x = "!!!!!";
        }
        result.push(x.substr(0, reminder + 1));
    }
    return result.join("");
};
```

The code of c function is below:

```js
var c = function (input, length, result) {
    var i, j, n, b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    for (i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
        n = ((input[i] * 256 + input[i + 1]) * 256 + input[i + 2])
            * 256 + input[i + 3];
        if (!n) {
            result.push("z");
        } else {
            for (j = 0; j < 5;
                b[j++] = n % 85 + 33, n = Math.floor(n / 85)
            );
        }
        result.push(String.fromCharCode(
            b[4], b[3], b[2], b[1], b[0]));
    }
};
```

Comment: Did an old school C programmer write that code? It's not very...JavaScript-y.

Comment: Also "stack and normal array at the same time" - I'm trying to see what of both is needed here, but until then on a hunch - would a List work? It implements the Stack interface and you can do `list.get(n)`.

Comment: Let me give it a try using a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) corresponds to [`List#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-):

```
t.add(0);
```

`List` has no analog for [`Array.prototype.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) but you can [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) the last element:

```
result.remove(t.size() - 1);
```

So the code could therefore be converted to use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), for example.

[`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) allows `push`/`pop` as well as access by index but its indexing is O(n).

There is also [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) which has `push`/`pop` and O(1) indexing, but it's a subclass of [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) which new code is generally steered away from using. (Basically `Vector`'s operations are synchronized for thread safety, which is a pointless overhead if the `Stack` isn't shared between threads. `Vector` is superseded by [`Collections.synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) in this regard, so `Stack` has a very niche feature set.)

I also don't see a problem with doing something like the following:

```
public class MyList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    public E pop() {
        return this.remove(this.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

It doesn't break Liskov Substitution Principle (still behaves as an `ArrayList`).

Comment: Sorrry, yes - I was looking at a different implementation of `List`

Comment: I think Vid's solution is also useful but have not tried it but I think it should also work. Thanks for your solutions too. :)

Comment: @Sunny I've mentioned `Stack` in my answer. Of course whatever you do is up to you. ; )